# Alternative to 'portfolio' covering non-visual fields?

Tags: single-word-requests

It seems that the word 'portfolio' is mostly used in the context of representing work in field of visual art, even, if it technically isn't restricted to that by definition. Are there other alternative words that would cover someone in Sciences, Social Sciences as well as the Arts when representing or showcasing their work? What would anyone in those fields call a collection of their work?

The only alternative that comes to mind is 'Showcase'.

Comment: I work in finance, and the entirely non-visual set of positions one has in tradeable securities is called an "[investment] *portfolio*". More specifically, I work as and with software vendors who service and sell to Wall St firms, and we often refer to our entirely non-visual catalog of software products our "[product] *portfolio*". Similarly, my sister-in-law is a high-powered executive in the unrelated field of real estate, and often speaks of the set of physical tracts of land and improvements upon them which her clients own their "[real-estate] *portfolio*".

Comment: I just realized that my previous comment reads as snarky or snide or at least brusque. My apologies, that was not my intent. I just wanted to give you concrete examples which should give you confidence that you can use *portfolio* to describe the software you've produced (or maybe even participated in) to prospective employers or clients or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

'Showcase' seems something that's more purely for the visual and performing arts. Although some fields do their own terms, such as filmography and [bibliography](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bibliography).

In non-research-based education, we still have portfolios to support our resumes. These might include examples of lesson plans, activities and materials we've developed, past evaluations and recommendation letters, among other things. Students might also have portfolios. As Dan mentioned in his comment, 'portfolio' is not limited to the arts; it's merely [a collection of examples of your work](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portfolio).

In research-based academia, professors usually have a 'curriculum vitae' that lists research and published papers rather than a resume (or in addition to). The list of published work is simply a 'publication history.'

'_____ history' is a fairly common phrase, a sort of catch-all. 'Case history' for professions that have cases, like social work and the legal field. 'Client history' for anyone with clients. 'Project history' for people whose work involves projects.